# Convert a string to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I convert the string test[1][2][3][4][5] to a multidimensional PHP array like:

```
array(1 => array(2 => array( 3 => array( 4 => array(5 => array()))));
```

Comment: What does `test` have to do with the result? Does it matter at all? Also, please share your attempts.

Comment: Did you mean to ask how you can create an multidimensional array that has just an empty array at a specific combination of indices?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you're asking to convert the string `"test[1][2][3][4][5]"` to `array(1 => array(2 => array( 3 => array( 4 => array(5 => array()))));`

First of all, people usually use the short `array()` notation, which is just `[]`.

Second, why use strings, when you can just type

```
$test[1][2][3][4][5] = [];
```

to get what you want.

---

If you really want strings, you can do it in several ways, one of which is:

```
function makeArrayFromString($string, &$name)
{
    $namePosEnd = strpos($string, '['); // name ends when first [ starts
    if (!$namePosEnd) return false; // didn't find [ or doesn't start with name

    $name = substr($string, 0, $namePosEnd);

    $dimensionKeys = [];
    $result = preg_match_all('/\[([0-9]+)\]/', $string, $dimensionKeys); // get keys
    if (!$result) return false; // no matches for dimension keys

    $dimensionKeys = array_reverse($dimensionKeys[1]);
    $multiArray = [];

    foreach ($dimensionKeys as $key)
    {
        $key = (int)$key; // we have string keys, turn them to integers
        $temp = [];
        $temp[$key] = $multiArray;
        $multiArray = $temp;
    }

    return $multiArray;
}

$string = 'test[1][2][3][4][5]';
$name = '';
$multiArray = makeArrayFromString($string, $name);

if ($multiArray === false)
    exit('Error creating the multidimensional array from string.');

$$name = $multiArray; // assign the array to the variable name stored in $name
var_dump($test); // let's check if it worked!
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [5]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that I didn't add any checks if the $name string satisfies the PHP variable naming rules. So you might get an error if you do something like `111onetest[1][2][3][4][5]`, as variable names in PHP can't start with a number.